# 2 Windows Forms 2 app.config files in 1 solution

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I have 2 windows forms in a solution and want to read some values from the respective config files of each app.

The second form is like an 'option/tool' from the first form. So in first form, I do:

```
someEventOfForm1...
{
 Form2 f = new Form2();
 f.ShowDialog();
}
```

Now, when 'f' tries to read from its config file, it ends up reading config file of first form. I want f to read its own config file.

- What should one do in such a scenario?
- Is it a bad design to open another form from one?

Comment: A form has no config file. Do you mean application? Are you deploying them to the same folder?

Comment: Yes, I meant, I have 2 different windows forms projects under a solution. And I am not deploying them to same folder.

Comment: Then they will NOT read each other's config file. How do you know they are?

Comment: On load of form 2, (from form1), I try to read app.config file (which is supposedly the app.config of form 2), but I don't see what I expect after form2 loads.

Comment: is that form2 belongs to one project(project 2) and form1 belongs to another project(project1) in solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should one do in such a scenario?

You can have only one application configuration file per application. Put the configuration settings for the project containing Form2 into the app.config file in the project containing Form1.

> Is it a bad design to open another form from one?

Not necessarily - it's often a fundamental strategy for creating multi-window applications.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one `app.config` per application. You may create XML document to save the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Create separable sections in 1 config file for each app you want to load and then load it from that config file.